# how to connect to WCF web service inside lan

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I am using wcf web service in my project (server-client) in local host mode and it works fine

now I need to connect to this service from another machine on the same local network

what should I change in the config file in my client ?

I changed the endpoint of my client to the IP of the machine that contains the local server and could not connect!

```
<endpoint address="http://10.131.40.22:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary_Test/Service1/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_RepositoryManager"
                contract="onlineExchangeCenter.RepositoryManager" name="WSHttpBinding_RepositoryManager">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
```

Comment: I also suspect that the firewall is blocking the port you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What errors are you getting? The issue could be firewall related.

I generally expose a MEX endpoint at the server and then generate the client config files through SVCutil.

Comment: ok it seems that you are right about the firewall, now i have this exception "The caller was not authenticated by the service" :(

Answer (score 0):

First - you need to add a new endpoint to your **service** - for a connection inside your corporate LAN, I would recommend the `netTcpBinding`:

```
<service name="someservice" behaviorConfiguration="....">
   <endpoint name="existing"
       address="......" 
       binding="wsHttpBinding"
       contract="onlineExchangeCenter.RepositoryManager" />

   <!-- add this *NEW* netTcpBinding endpoint -->
   <endpoint name="corporateLAN"
       address="net.tcp://YourServer:7171/YourService/SomeUrl" 
       binding="netTcpBinding"
       contract="onlineExchangeCenter.RepositoryManager" />
</service>
```

Once you have this in place, you should update your client - either do a "right-click" on your service reference in Visual Studio and pick "Update Service Reference", or manually add this endpoint information to your client-side config, so that your client will now connect to the `netTcp` endpoint on your server.

NetTcp is great in a LAN environment, but the ports used need to be open - if you have any firewalls or ISA servers inside your corporate environment, you might need to open these ports in order for this to work