# Host Service Visual Studio Development Server for Access over the LAN

Tags: c#, wcf, lan

I'm trying to host a service and access it through a local network.

This is a part of my app.config:

```
 <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://<my IP>:49770/Service1.svc"
            binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="LAN" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:49770/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
```

The localhost endpoint works great if I work on one machine but the LAN endpoint won't work. 
This is the code I use to connect via the LAN endpoint.

```
 ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new
           ServiceReference1.Service1Client("LAN");
```

I read this post but it still won't work:

[how to connect to WCF web service inside lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086731/how-to-connect-to-wcf-web-service-inside-lan)

Comment: Have you added a firewall rule to allow port 49770 TCP incoming in the windows firewall?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I did it now but still can't connect.

Comment: Maybe it's wrong that the asp.net developer server starts with localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development server can't accept remote connections. You have to use a proper IIS instance for that.

Comment: I don't get it. Why would they even create a development server if it can't host a wcf service? Now I'm trying to get a proper IIS instance for my service but that's not easy...